# Why I got csrss.exe error at application exit?

Tags: c#, sockets, csrss

I faced a problem and I need your help. 
There is an exe application, which runs a .net socket, accepts and handle requests. I'm sending to this a "terminate" command, which stops the server, finalize the threads, and teminate the appication. It works usually, but sometimes(after 5-10 cycle) I recieve a red message box window like "XXX.exe - Application error The exception unknown software eexception (0x0000417) occured in the application at location 0x0000000006968AF3E. Click on OK to terminate the program"

This error throwed by the csrss.exe, not from my XXX.exe. I see in the taskmanager.

I started to watch the XXX.exe and the csrss.exe processes lifecycle. Before the XXX.exe close, an another XXX.exe instance appeared in the tasklist with differenct PID. The lifetime of this second process is only 200-1100ms. The csrss.exe error windows appears at the same time, when this second process terminates.

The XXX.exe does not start any second instance of himself by code. I don't know how this second instance is started, but after a lot of investigation I found out that the parent process of the second instance is the same exe. If the problem occurs, I faced this second instance. If it works, there is no second instance.

I'm working with this problem in the last 2 weeks and will really appreciate and idea or new point of view! The XXX.exe is a c# appliation, the enviroment is windows 10